# Pattern for specific regex VBA excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel, pattern-matching

I have a string like this : "+33 (0)1 75 32 33 34", i want this result : +331 75 32 33 34
And I fail to find the pattern to use to have this result

Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `\s*\([^)]+\)`

Replace by `empty string`.

Comment: I want to remove parantheses and value inside only if the value is 0, if the value in the parantheses is for example 1 I just want to remove parantheses but not the value. Do you know if it is possible or not ?

Comment: @JeromeCampeaux `\s*\(0\)|\s*\([^0)]+\)`

Comment: @ vks I tried to undestand your regex but i don't understand it. And I still have an issue + (33) (0) 1 55 24 72 67 become + 1 55 24 72 67 and I want +331 55 24 72 67. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: `\s*\(0\)|\s*\(([1-9])\)` try this @JeromeCampeaux replace by `$1`.

Comment: I have this + (33) 1 55 24 72 67